# help - how to calculate distance between to points ( latitude/longtitude) without ACOS / ATAN

Tags: calculator

I need to calculate the distance between to points (latitude/longitude) in **WebI** (SAP system) and I have limited formulas there (don't have : `ACOS` / `ATAN` / `ATAN2`) I have `COS` / `SIN`. 
I found this formula : `(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-X1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-X2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-X1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-X2)) *COS(RADIANS(Y1-Y2))) *6371)*1000`

but I don't have the `ACOS` formula in **Web Intelligence** (**WebI** - SAP ) , if anyone know maybe how to calculate `ACOS`?

Will appreciate it so much, Mor :)

Comment: I do not know anything about your WebI but if you need x from  acos(x) = y for x and you not have access to acos, solve x = cos(y). If you need more about this, just contact me.

Comment: I know that , but it's not helping me to solve it .. :\

Comment: I can provide you some approximate formulas but I am afraid they would be not sufficiently accurate close to 1.

Comment: Are you still concerned or not by this problem ?

Comment: yes. any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Let us remember that ArcCos[x]+ArcSin[x]=Pi/2 and that ArcCos[x]=ArcSin[Sqrt[1-x^2]]; I shall assume that x is positive. Then, what you could do is to use Taylor expansions of one or the other functions depending on the value of x. I suggest you switch at x=0.5.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series
gives you the general formulas.

There are other alternates such as Pade approximants (you can google for them or I could provide them to you if required). I think that the limitation is : how many terms are you ready to accept for any of these expansions (this is related to the desired accuracy).

We can continue discussing this topic if you want.